# sass animation did not work after adding a transition-timing function

Tags: css, sass

i wanted to create a box with a border and inside it a small div, i wanted when i have a hover over the box the small div inside it will start to animate and but the animation did not start at all, so i deleted hover also the animation did not work in this case too,

here what i have tried:

```
<div class="row mb-4">
      <div class="col col__animation">
        <div id="object"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Scss:

```
.col__animation{  
    display: flex;
    border-radius: 1rem !important;
    border: 1px solid #284876;
    height: 200px !important;
    align-items: center;
    
    #object {
        width: 40px;
        height: 50px;
        background: blueviolet;
        margin-top: 2px;
        margin-bottom: 1px;
        margin-right: 3px;
    }
    
    &:hover{
        #object{
            transition: transform 1000ms;
            transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        }
    }

}
```

I am trying to try many animations effects like making the box move to right and go back to initial position and many more animations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
.col__animation {
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 1rem !important;
  border: 1px solid #284876;
  height: 200px !important;
  align-items: center;
}

.col__animation #object {
  width: 40px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blueviolet;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  animation: mymove 3s infinite;
}

@keyframes mymove {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }

  50% {
    margin-left: calc(100% - 40px);
  }

  100% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/KaungKZ/pen/eYWBROO)

Comment: great! the animation is working but i noticed that it is just going for 100px as a distance and then coming back , how to make it go until the end ? should i replace  100px by 100% or something?

Comment: and it is possible to make animations running the whole time without a hover?

Comment: You can make it go until the end by `margin` value and use `keyframes` and set animation time to `infinite` to make it run the whole time. I've also updated the codes.

Comment: Keep in mind that I didn't use `sass` for this so you might need to transform this css to `sass` on you own.